# Esbuild & Typescript namespaces merge into bundle not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces, esbuild

I have following code. I want use single namespace Namespace1 for classes, but I don't know how to merge then without module imports. I think that if everything works in both the IDE and TS (npx tsc), there should be no problem in bundling. if I use modules, the composition in TS is not correct. Type detections, such as `someMethod (in: Namesace1.Class1)`, do not work.

I bundle everything in **esbuild**. Is there a way to do this? It's possible to merge necessary files into bundle without import? Is it possible that this is an esbuild error?

**class1.ts**:

```
namespace Namespace1 {
    export class Class1 {
    }
}
```

**class2.ts**:

```
namespace Namespace1 {
    export class Class2 {
    }
}
```

**index.ts**:

```
let class1 = new Namespace1.Class1();
console.log(class1);

let class2 = new Namespace1.Class2();
console.log(class2);
```

In IDE(Visual studio) and TSC check is ok, but result bundle look like this - class definition totaly missing:

```
(() => {
  // src/index.tsx
  var class1 = new Namespace1.Class1();
  console.log(class1);
  var class2 = new Namespace1.Class2();
  console.log(class2);
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```